# Is it possible to use EventSubscribers with Silex?

Tags: php, silex

Whilst looking around at using AuthenticationHandlers I saw that Symfony supports EventSubscribers which can be more flexible when authenticating with multiple methods.

I have been using this as an example: https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/guard/success-handling

So I have got my subscriber class all setup, but what I do not know how to do is register is as an event in Silex.

I am pretty sure that I need to use the `$app['dispatcher']` but what I do not know is what event to listen on.  Using the example from the page, in a Symfony configuration, the servics is tagged with `kernel.event_subscriber` but when I did the following in Silex nothing happened:

`$app['dispatcher'] -> addListener(KernelEvents::EVENT_SUBSCRIBER, function(Event $event) use ($app) {
       ... do something ...
});`

I am pretty sure that the event I listening on is wrong, but I did not get any errors either.  Is this sort of thing possible in Silex?

thanks, Russell

**Update:**

This is my subscriber class:

```
<?php

namespace MySubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\SecurityEvents;

class ApiKeySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  public function onInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event) {

    file_put_contents("/tmp/onInteractiveLogin.txt", "It was ehere");

  }

  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return array(SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => 'onInteractiveLogin');
  }
}
```

The firewall is very simple:

```
    // Configure the firewalls for the application
    $app['security.firewalls'] = array(
        'basicauth' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/auth',
            'http' => true,
            'users' => $app -> share(function() use ($app) {
                return new UserAccount($app);
            })
        )
    );
```

And then I add the subscriber with:

```
$app['dispatcher'] -> addSubscriber(new \MySubscriber\ApiKeySubscriber());
```

I assume that Basic Auth qualifies as interactive login, so I am not sure why the method is not being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subscriber class should implement `EventSubscriberInterface`. If it does, just use the `addSubscriber` method instead of `addListener`.

```
$app['dispatcher']->addSubscriber(new MyEventSubscriber());
```

Your event subscriber has a method called `getSubscribedEvents` that tells Symfony what events to subscribe to so you don't need to pass an event name at all. See [the Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html#using-event-subscribers) for more information.

**Update** (security listener):

The basic HTTP authentication method is not considered interactive login. That is for a typical web based login form.

You may be able to use `AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS` instead. Your listener method will receive an `AuthenticationEvent` instance.

```
<?php
namespace MySubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\AuthenticationEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Event\AuthenticationEvent;

class ApiKeySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
  public function onAuthenticate(AuthenticationEvent $event)
  {
    file_put_contents("/tmp/onInteractiveLogin.txt", "It was here");
  }

  public static function getSubscribedEvents()
  {
    return array(AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS => 'onAuthenticate');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, that makes sense.  My subscriber does indeed implement the EventSubscriberInterface, I have updated my answer.  What I am not sure about is why the 'onInteractiveLogin' is not being called.  I do not get the file being created.  I am using an firewall with basic auth.

Comment: Great thanks, I will try that later.  If 'Basic Auth' is not considered an Interactive login, would the same hold true for SuccessHandlers?  I have been trying to get that to work with HTTP auth as well but have a suspicion this is not supported, which would explain why my SuccessHandler is not working.  I appreciate that Handlers and Subscribers are different things and I probably do not need both.

Comment: thanks for this.  Just got to testing this and it now works a treat.